# is mingw designed for windows platform c++ program?

Tags: c++, mingw

I write code in mingw and eclipse, use sleep(10) and

```
include <unistd.h>
```

, but it can't found anyone definition,

```
error: 'sleep' was not declared in this scope
```

but I choose it to Sleep(10) without any include, it is ok.
So from this view, if the mingw is designed for windows platform in C++ area?
If I want to write code for linux platform. if I had to make sure all the code is suitable for Linux?

Comment: The right choice is `std::this_thread::sleep_for`.

Comment: MinGW does not provide a POSIX emulation layer. For that you'll want Cygwin. MinGW only provides extremely minimal compatibility, it's really just GCC (the compiler) for Windows (the API).

Comment: except gcc tool+windows api, what are mingw provide?

Comment: The home page http://www.mingw.org/ sums it pretty well: MinGW is just a toolchain (ie. a compiler + linker) in a native WinAPI environment. Fact is, you can also use MinGW on Cygwin (POSIX layer) but this is a whole other matter, you'd need Cygwin in the first place which is a totally different product than MinGW.